# Getting Forbidden Error While Restricting Access to AWS Managed Grafana Using VPC Endpoint with Network Access Control

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I am using AWS managed Grafana in one of the projects.
I am able to access Grafana workspace URL without using Network Access Control as it allowed over the internet.
But I need to restrict the access  within our organization for which I am using Network Access Control with VPC endpoint in AMG.
I have created the VPC endpoint and added it to AMG but I am getting forbidden error now.
Could you please help me to fix this issue?

I need to restrict the access  within our organization for which I am using Network Access Control with VPC endpoint in AMG.
I have created the VPC endpoint and added it to AMG.
Also, I have created Network LB and added the private IP address of VPC endpoint DNS name to target group.
Not sure I am doing it in right way, please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: I'm looking for the same configuration and i cant get it working, do you have any update on this?